# proper implementation of binomial distribution?

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to get binomial distribution to return a value within a range with a higher probability of being in the lower spectrum, and all I can get it to return is 37. Here's my implementation:

```
int32_t binomial_random(int32_t minNumber, int32_t maxNumber, float modifier) {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    static std::binomial_distribution<int> binomialRand(maxNumber, modifier);
    return minNumber + binomialRand(generator);
}
```

and when i call it:

```
level = binomial_random(minLevel, maxLevel-minLevel, 0.3f);
```

it appears to be returning 37 regardless of minLevel and maxLevel

Comment: You're creating a new generator every time you call the function. Make it `static` as well.

Comment: thank you, that made it random, i'll mess with the modifier number now because it's returning way higher than intended(i thought 0.3 would be like 3 of 10, but i'm inputting 1 for min level, 5 for max level and it's returning like 20

Comment: How about `binomialRand(maxNumber-minNumber, modifier); return minNumber + binomialRand(generator);` ?